# Chrome: Is it possible to detect losing window focus to the javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Specific to google chrome: I'm trying to detect when a page loses focus, but not when it loses focus to the javascript console / other dev tools (i.e. the page is still the primary focus).

Any ideas?

I've tried using `window.onblur` and `visibilitychange` events.

Short use case: I'm working on a game and for some reason when it's running my editor (sublime text 2 on OSX) slows to a crawl.  If I change window focus it's fine.  So I'm trying to pause the game when I go to my editor but leave it running when I'm in the javascript console

[edit]

Since my question is apparently unclear, trying to clarify: I want to be able to tell the difference between:

- switching tabs, switching apps
- going to the javascript console

Comment: @Givi - `document.hasFocus()` is always true in chrome, so no go :(  There is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64846) on this from late 2010 that hasn't been fixed yet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

has a great snippet

Comment: hmm it's works for me try this and then switch window 
setTimeout(function() { alert(document.hasFocus()); }, 2000);

Comment: @Givi - I did, I put it on a timer every second, I get nothing but "true", even when switching tabs / apps

Comment: It works for me like clockwork ;)

Comment: document.body.onblur will work for non focused elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/kqEZn/

Comment: @Givi - chrome version / OS?

Comment: Version 27.0.1453.94 m / Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: @Givi - maybe it's an OSX issue then, none of my versions of chrome say anything other than "true" :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't really detect if the focus is on the dev tool or not, the best you can do is to detect if you opened the dev tool:

```
var focused = true;

$(window).blur(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(!isInspectOpen()) {
            alert("Focus lost.");
            focused = false;
        }
    }, 500);
});
$(window).focus(function () {
    if(!focused) {
        alert("Focus gained.");
        focused = true;
    }
});

function isInspectOpen() {
    console.profile();
    console.profileEnd();
    if(console.clear) console.clear();
    return console.profiles.length > 0;
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NtPPR/

Comment: Interesting idea :)  Any ideas for how to do this in chrome?  `console.profiles` doesn't exist

Comment: haha, stopped working less than two weeks ago: https://codereview.chromium.org/15816002

Comment: maybe, I'm using dev/canary which are both at 29, and even if the other channels are still at 28, this is going to be gone soon :(

Comment: How would you write this with vanilla javascript and not jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

window.onfocus? I really don't understand what do you mean but look at this references. Search for "events":

[DOM document reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document)

[DOM reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Hope it help you!

Comment: In which case the console looses focus?

Comment: I think you never loose console focus. Are you talking about javascript console?

Comment: Yes, the JS console.  Or anything else in the dev tools